# Update the provider array & increment count only if providerId is not there in Document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am stuck in a situation like this. I have the following document.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ceba7c419b48423e452972a"),
    "userId" : ObjectId("5ceba7c419b48423e4529727"),
    "providers" : [ 
        "1689736266", 
        "1598763690", 
        "1528069614", 
        "1831364272", 
        "1548463045", 
        "1245301159", 
        "1386616399", 
        "1790775971", 
        "1629462130", 
        "1992169783"
    ],
    "countByType" : {
        "doctors" : 6,
        "labs" : 0,
        "hospitals" : 0,
        "imagingCenters" : 0,
        "other" : 4
    }
}
```

Initially, I fetch the providerArray from elastic search, added to providers array and incremented the count by using the following query.

```
let updateProviderId = await userProviderCollection.update(
   regUserId, {
     $set:  {
       providers: combinedProviderArray,
       countByType: providerCountType
     }
});
```

where combinedProviderArray is a combined array of providers. ProviderId is created when a new report is generated. The above condition will work if reports already there.
But when a new report comes, I need to check in providers array and increment the count if not in an array, else do nothing. How can I achieve this.

Please see the code below when a report with providerId is already in an array.

```
// Searching for Providers in Elastic Search
   let searchForProviders = await esHelper.getProvidersById(combinedProviderArray, true);
   searchForProviders.forEach((getCategory) => {
     let prCategory = getCategory.category;
     prCategory.forEach((cat) => {

       // Combining categories
       categoryArray = categoryArray.concat(cat);
     });
   });

   let counts = {
     "doctor": 0,
     "laboratory": 0,
     "hospital": 0,
     "imagingcenter": 0,
     "other": 0
   };
   let x;
   categoryArray.forEach(function(x) {
     counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0)+1;
   });

   let providerCountType = {
     "doctors": counts.doctor,
     "labs": counts.laboratory,
     "hospitals": counts.hospital,
     "imagingCenters": counts.imagingcenter,
     "other": counts.other
   }


   // Updating npiId & category count
   userproviderData.getDataSource().connector.connect(async (err, db) => {
     let userProviderCollection = db.collection("UserProviders");
     let regUserId = { userId: userId};
     let updateProviderId = await userProviderCollection.update(
       regUserId, {
         $set:  {
           providers: combinedProviderArray,
           countByType: providerCountType
         }
       });
   });
```

Please provide an appropriate solution for the same. Any help would be really appreciated. I am stuck on how to add a provider to array & increment the count according to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of rebuilding the array every time, you can use `$addToSet`. This has the effect of adding the value to the array, but only if it is not already present...

```
let updateProviderId = await userProviderCollection.update(
   regUserId, {
     $addToSet:  {
       providers: providerID
     }
});
```

As for the counts, it can be done similarly, using $inc.

```
let updateProviderId = await userProviderCollection.update(
   regUserId, {
     $inc:  {
       "countByType.doctors": 1
     }
});
```

You could build your increment object easily:

```
let $inc= {
  "countByType.doctors": counts.doctor,
  "countByType.labs": counts.laboratory,
  "countByType.hospitals": counts.hospital,
  "countByType.imagingCenters": counts.imagingcenter,
  "countByType.other": counts.other
}
let updateProviderId = await userProviderCollection.update(regUserId, {$inc});
```

If you are just adding one, and want to do everything at the same time, you could just the first 2 examples:

```
let $inc = {};
$inc["countByType."+categoryName] =  1;
let updateProviderId = await userProviderCollection.update(
   regUserId, {
     $addToSet:  {
       providers: providerID
     },
     $inc
});
```

But it would increment the count even tough the provider was already present... So you'd need to check if the $addToSet worked, and then do the increment:

```
let updateProviderId = await userProviderCollection.update(
   regUserId, {
     $addToSet:  {
       providers: providerID
     }
});
if(updateProviderId["nMatched"] === 1 //A document was matched
    && updateProviderId["nModified"] === 1 //A document was modified
){
    let updateProviderCount = await userProviderCollection.update(regUserId, {$inc});
}
```

Comment: Could you please show me a way to update both providerArray and update count in a single update query using $addToSet. I didnt get you the way. Can you please explain little bit? Sorry

Comment: If you dont mind can you please have a look into my files or can we have a direct chat?

Comment: I am sorry, not really... No time to do that. Second to last snippet does update count and set at the same time.

Comment: Can you please provide the code as one file? It will be good for me to understand..

Comment: No, I will not glue everything together for you. The main reason being how will you learn if someone always does it for you?

Comment: Please provide the same, because different snippets shown above are little bit confusing for me.. Sorry